# Can not connect to google

Tags: networking, wireless, dns, 20.04, google

I am using ubuntu 20.04 with hp laptop with rtl8723be driver. I can not connect to google when on wifi. I can access other url. Google shows this error in browser

```
This site can’t be reached www.google.co.in unexpectedly closed the connection.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

I tried to edit a file(suggested by some articles. I forgot the name of the file) and added nameserver 8.8.8.8 but it didn't work for me.

Output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

Output of `ping -c3 8.8.8.8`

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=99.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=67.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=68.6 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 67.856/78.493/99.054/14.541 ms
```

Output of `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Jan 20 00:12 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is `ufw` enabled? Try disabling it `sudo ufw disable`

Comment: @ldias I tried the command but it's still not working. Should I keep ufw disabled?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and finally: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Look at `ip route`. You should have a `default` route pointing to your WiFi.

Comment: Is the behavior the same if you put in the address bar www.google.co.in or preceded by http:// or else preceded with https:// ?

Comment: Right now, it's mysteriously working